# Скрипт времени загрузки страницы, с передачей времени к переменной

Tags: php, javascript, pure_js

Доброго всем времени суток

Ищу скрипт загрузки страницы, да не простой... охота без всякого типа jquery, только на js, опять же без доп файлов и библиотек. Найти в инете такой можно, но вот беда... выводить время загрузки страницы мне не нужно, нужно лишь приравнять к переменной (скажем к `$load_time`), и я уже сам решу, надо ли его "echo" или нет. Есть ли у кого такой?

Comment: Можно "приравнять" php-переменную к js. Не наоборот. По крайней мере, во время загрузки страницы без подзапросов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

а не подойдет

```
<?
$load_time_start = mktime();

//исполняемый код

$load_time = mktime() - $load_time_start;
?>
```

Comment: мб microtime?

Comment: Если важны только секунды, то mktime(), а если важны микросекунды, то microtime(1) надо поставить естественно.

Comment: Хотя да, наверное, microtime лучше подходит.